# Is there a way to write a script that checks every few minutes if another python process is running and reruns it if necessary?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am aware how to check if some python process is running. I am trying to write a script, which checks whether a python script is running, if it is not it should rerun it.

What I have right now is:

```
import os


stream = os.popen("ps aux | grep combined.py")
output = stream.read()
print(output[0])
```

The problem is I can't get the specific process ID this way, because `output`  is a list of characters not a dict, where I could get PID by output["PID"], to check whether there is an PID in the list.

How would I implement such script?

Comment: so.... `pgrep`?

Comment: You question is about "how to", but you should maybe ask (e.g. in unix linux stack exchange) about the existing tools which already monitor processes. Personally I would not reinvent the wheel again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`ps -ef |grep combined.py |grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}'`
echo $pid
```

You can use crontab to run the bash script and checks every few minutes if the python process is running

Comment: Excuse me, i check your edit but I don't understand the question, could you ask it differently? Thank you!

Comment: It actually works now, no need. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Grateful to be able to help!